# readline() returns nothing when run from certain file

Tags: python, function, methods, readline

I've been working on a project lately which requires me to **get a value stored in a text file**. Simple task, right?

I have tried pretty much every stupid solution that uses **readline()** at some point, but when it's printed, there's nothing. Debug also tells me that it is empty.

Since I've experienced some inconsistencies with python already, I tried using the **same function inside a different python file**, and running it does exactly what it's supposed to do.

My current solution (not the best, but currently I just want it to run properly) is

```
count_file = "count.txt"
filehandle = open(count_file, 'r')
line = filehandle.readline()
print(line)
```

which works fine when used in a file called "**test.py**". When used in my "**main.py**", it returns nothing. And yes, I used it on the same context and temporarily deleted everything else from the main file while testing.

Does anyone have a clue what causes this? I could just paste the other stuff into the test file and rename it, but 1. that's annoying and 2. it'd be useful to know how to avoid this.

**EDIT**: I am not certain yet, but I think that the problem is caused by my IDE (am using the latest version of Pycharm Professional). I solved the problem by deleting and re-adding the Run/Debug Configuration.

Comment: re-naming the file should make no difference (unless you import it somewhere)

Comment: before using readline, try `filehandle.seek(0)` then whats the output?

Comment: what happens when you use `filehandle.read()` or `filehandle.readlines()`? Perhaps there's some hidden characters at the start of the file

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will get return value as None if you do not specify the file path. please check the path/relative path of "`count.txt`" file with respect to "`main.py`" script.

Comment: Might try this the next time I get weird python behavior like this. I am not certain yet, but I think that the problem is caused by my IDE (am using the latest version of Pycharm Professional). I solved the problem by deleting and re-adding the Run/Debug Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First point: your file path is relative, so it will be resolved according to the current working directory, NOT depending on your script's location.

Second point: you read a single line, it can indeed be empty or only contains non-printable characters.

Third point: run your code without pycharm. Pycharm is probably fine when you really understand what it does behind your back, but if you don't you will indeed experiment some unexpected results. Just using the command line and a simple code editor is actually much simpler (though possibly not as productive) and less confusing.

And finally, don't forget you have an interactive Python shell. Quite handy for testing out things...